# Regex to find special characters in a String with some exceptions

Tags: regex

I just had a similar (but not exact) question answered. Now I need help with the question mentioned below.

I want to write a regex which matches a character if its a non word, non digit and non star (*) character. So, the characters `[0-9][a-z][A-Z] *` should not match and the others should.

I tried writing `[\W[^*]]` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
[^\w\*]
```

Comment: this wont check for the character *

Answer (score 7):

The simplest regular expression that matches a single character, that is not one of those you described, independent of any particular regular-expression extensions, would be:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z *]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[^\w\*]
```

Simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following regex:

```
[\W_]
```